# Is "Your account is pending activation." correct?

Tags: grammaticality, parts-of-speech

> Your account is pending activation.

I have seen this sentence on some websites after an account creation. Is this sentence correct? If so, is *pending activation* an adjective?

Comment: Pending is a verb. Activation is a noun.

Comment: "Pending activation" is a _verb phrase_ serving as the _complement_ of the copula.

Comment: I think it should be - > Your account activation is pending

Comment: Even if this for some reason isn't grammatically correct, it's definitely a perfectly acceptable idiom. I'm not a grammar expert, but I'm a native speaker...to me, "pending activation" seems like an adjectival phrase. "Pending activation" is the "state" your account is in.

Comment: @mlecoz, I really appreciate your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your sentence is grammatically and idiomatically correct. "Pending activation" describes the current status of your account.

Answer (score 0):

Your account is pending activation.

The sentence is grammatical.

The term pending is a preposition in the sentence.  If something is done/is depending a future event, it's done/is in a state until that event happens.  The word activation is a future event here.  Another example:

Hs was released on bail until further inquiries (Oxford).

The "pending" can also be used as an adjective. For example:

It's a pending case.

This case is still pending.